# How to remove a marker from leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, marker

I have a marker in my leaflet map like

```
marker = new L.Marker([lat,lon],{icon:flagIcon,title: "Drage me to change your location"}).addTo(map);
              marker.dragging.enable();
              marker.on('dragend', function(e){
                  var coords = e.target.getLatLng();
                  var lat = coords.lat;
                  var lon = coords.lng;
                  console.log("Lat : "+lat+"  Lng: "+lon);
                  document.getElementById("lat").value=lat;
                  document.getElementById("long").value=lon;
                  document.getElementById("placeName").value="location on map";
                  updateAnchor();
                  map.panTo({lon:lon,lat:lat})
                  if(flag!=0){
                      map.removeLayer(cir);
                      cir = L.circle([lat,lon],circleOptions).addTo(map);
                      refreshMarkers(flag);
                   }
              });
```

If the marker is already exist i want to remove it and and a new one.For that i added a code like

```
if (marker) {
    map.removeLayer(marker); // remove
}
```

But i couldn't remove the older marker.How to solve this issue

Comment: pls share the code of `updateAnchor()` and `refreshMarkers(flag)`. Also you can add the coords directly `map.panTo(coords); L.circle(coords, ...`

Comment: @FalkeDesign that is not a problem.Because i just commented those marker on drag end method.But still have the same problem.So the problem is marker is not removing

Comment: When you looking in https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/v2dn3xLt/ the marker is removing when you click on it. So it has something to do with `updateAnchor` or `refreshMarkers` or other code. Are you overwriting the marker variable?

Comment: @FalkeDesign yes i am overwriting the same variable.is there any problem in that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `marker` you're adding isn't the same object as the `marker` that's already on the map. If you want to be able to reference (eg to remove) a marker later, save a copy of the marker object in a global.

```
var oldmarker;

marker = <your code here>
oldmarker = marker;
```

Then

```
if (map.hasLayer(oldmarker)) {
    map.removeLayer(oldmarker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (map.hasLayer(marker)) {
    map.removeLayer(marker); // remove
}
```

If this is not helping pls add more code to your question, when do you want to remove the marker and how you add the new one

Comment: I tried like this.But still not removing the old one.making both old and new

Comment: I just done a console print inside that if statement.The if statement is executing.But the removing process is not working